# Why does Calamares think there isn't enough space?

Tags: package-management, disk-usage

I am exploring the Maui distro and this is my first experience with Calamares.
During the 'prepare' stage of Calamares it complains that my system doesn't have at least 6GB of available drive space.
This is a fresh install, splitting my 500GB drive pretty much 50/50 root/home so I'm not sure where Calamares is failing to find the 6GB.

Why would Calamares think there isn't enough space? I thought by just allocating root and home the installer would be smart enough to distrobute disk space as needed.
Or as a start, where can I find the log files for Calamares?

$fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002d458

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048   420446207   209710080   83  Linux
/dev/sda3       420446208   976768064   278160928+  83  Linux
```

$df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       197G  1.6G  186G   1% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G   76K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G  620K  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.9G  8.0K  1.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1       485M   28M  432M   6% /boot
/dev/sda3       262G   92M  248G   1% /home
tmpfs           375M     0  375M   0% /run/user/996
tmpfs           375M  8.0K  375M   1% /run/user/100000
```

Comment: You might want to give us your partition scheme, maybe the output of `sudo fdisk -l` if you can. That of `df -h` might be nice as well.

Comment: I've updated the question with the info. There's no specific file system for usr so I would assume it comes under root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be that the OS on my machine was the same as the live image on the thumb drive I used to install it.
When I called calamares it was attempting to reinstall the entire operating system again.
The reason for the disk space issue was that calamares needed root privileges.

My takeaway from this is that my distro (Maui) simply isn't quite ready to be used out of the box and requires manual building/installation of packages.